# How to set datas with css style with CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

How can I set datas with CKEditor (4.0) with CSS style ?

```
$quote = $editor + '<br />'+ 
        '<div class="quote">'+
            '<div class="quote-infos">'+
                '<i class="icon-comment icon-white"></i>'+
                ' <span class="quote-user">'+$user+'</span>,'+
                ' <span class="quote-date">'+$date+'</span> :'+
            '</div>'+
            '<blockquote>'+$div.html()+'</blockquote>'+
        '</div>';   
editorMessage.setData($quote);
```

In this code, when I send the datas to a POST form, I just have `<div><div><i></i><span`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new 4.1 CKEditor, it might be because of the new [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) feature. It nukes tags, attributes and attribute contents from content HTML, see [demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#acf). Turn it off by adding `config.allowedContent = true` to your config. More info on configuration in the [API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent)

You can test for this easily in your CKE instance by going to source mode, adding some attributes manually into the content, like `<div class="MagicalPonies"><div><i></i><span`... Then switch to wysiwyg mode and back to source mode. If your class definition is missing, it's most likely ACF. Also try to add a class like `<img alt="X" class="left" src="http://b.cksource.com/a/1/img/sample.jpg" />` and see if that sticks. Standard CKE classes like that aren't removed.

Comment: But doing a `config.allowedContent = true` will allow the <script> tags. No other option ?

Comment: ACF is configurable (far more than `true`). See [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules) to know more. You can also specify [config.extraAllowedContent](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent).